# Indexing in many to many relationship grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domains Class A and Class B with many to many relationship. For performance tuning I want to add indexes in a_id,b_id columns of table a_b(table produced by grails). FYI I have added the indexes from query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to create the index within the database itself. If there was an option to index the join table it'd likely be in the [joinTable()](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html), but it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial very helpful with many to many relationship in Grails.

[Many-to-Many Mapping without Hibernate XML](https://grails.org/wiki/Many-to-Many%20Mapping%20without%20Hibernate%20XML)

This method will give you the separate index unlike joinTable().